# how to downgrade dut_error to dut_warning in specman

Tags: specman

I have a test where I am using a expect @eventA-> eventually @eventB
else dut_error

However, my test treats that dut_error as a dut_warning and the test passed.
Is there any runtime switch in specman that downgrades all dut_errors to dut_warnings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set_check can change the error level.

```
extend sys {
   setup() is also {
        set_check("...", WARNING);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

For changing the effect of all checks, you cal also issue
"set check WARNING"

I recommend that you give names to the checks, among other things - it simplifies controlling their effect.

e.g. -

expect data_flow is @eventA-> eventually @eventB else  ...

and then -

set check -name = my_checker.data_flow WARNING;

A nice thing is that if you name the expect, you can override it.

expect data_flow @eventA-> {[3..13]; @eventB} else  ...

Comment: This was a useful tip ! I wonder if the other way is possible ? i.e I do a set_check globally to WARNING but just make one check as an error. I will try it out.